# C++ QuickSorting a vector and keeping the original index numbers

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort

I have a working quicksort function, but I'm not sure how to retain the original index numbers of the unsorted data. Any ideas? Thanks! Here's my function. Can I incorporate a pair in there somehow?

```
double NearestNeighbor::partition(vector<double>& theList, double start, double end) {
int pivot = theList[end];
int bottom = start - 1;
int top = end;

bool notdone = true;
while (notdone) {
    while (notdone) {
        bottom += 1;

        if (bottom == top) {
            notdone = false;
            break;
        }
        if (theList[bottom] > pivot) {
            theList[top] = theList[bottom];
            break;
        }
    }
    while (notdone) {
        top = top - 1;

        if (top == bottom) {
            notdone = false;
            break;
        }
        if (theList[top] < pivot) {
            theList[bottom] = theList[top];
            break;
        }
    }
}
theList[top] = pivot;
return top;
```

}

//quickSort function

```
double NearestNeighbor::quickSort(vector<double>& theList, double start, double end) {
if (start < end) {
    double split = partition(theList, start, end); //recursion   
    quickSort(theList, start, split - 1);
    quickSort(theList, split + 1, end);
} else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

I have calculated the dot product of several vectors and I'm trying to print the 10 nearest neighbors. I can sort them, but my professor as asked that we return the index number of the 10 nearest neighbors, so I'm trying to figure out how to retain those original index numbers.

for example: sorted data might look something like this:

index number:3  45 15 9 45
 data:            10 14 17 30 35

I want to print out just the index numbers. Sorry, I can't figure out how to format it so the numbers line up with the data, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: You should include a lot more with your question.  Some code, and examples of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert the `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<std::pair<int, T>>`.
2. Sort the `std::vector<std::pair<int, T>>` using the second of the `pair`.

Comment: When I change it as recommended, I get this error: error: cannot convert '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::pair<int, double> > >::value_type {aka std::pair<int, double>}' to 'int' in initialization
----I get it at this line "int pivot = theList[end];" I'm not sure what to do about this...

Comment: @user3882751, you'll have to account for the fact that `theList[end]` is a `pair`, not an `int`. `int pivot = theList[end].second;` is what you need.